# Cordova contacts html won't work

Tags: cordova, web, browser, contacts

I tried everything but I won't get the cordova plugin for contacts working within my web browser.

I even copied the example of the cordova page https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/cordova/contacts/Contact/contact.html and uploaded it to my web server. If I open the page on my iPhone I don't get anything from my contacts.

What do I do wrong? Or is it, that the way I check this on my phone is false? Can a browser even pick contacts from my phone?

I spent a whole weekend to get this working on my phone, set up everything as mentioned in the web, even made some native pages which only should grab a contact - nothing! I'm stuck!

Can anybody help with an example that works fine in a web browser?

as mentioned, it can also be that I misunderstand the whole thing, but as read in the web, html 5.0 should be able to grab contacts. Navigator.contacts.create or navigator.contacts.find for example didn't work in any of the tests I did. Always got an error in js.

Thank you very much in advance.

Sven

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // create
        var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
        contact.displayName = "Plumber";
        contact.nickname = "Plumber";       //specify both to support all devices
        var name = new [ContactName](../ContactName/contactname.html)();
        name.givenName = "Jane";
        name.familyName = "Doe";
        contact.name = name;

        // save
        contact.save(onSaveSuccess,onSaveError);

        // clone
        var clone = contact.clone();
        clone.name.givenName = "John";
        console.log("Original contact name = " + contact.name.givenName);
        console.log("Cloned contact name = " + clone.name.givenName); 

        // remove
        contact.remove(onRemoveSuccess,onRemoveError);
    }

    // onSaveSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSaveSuccess(contact) {
        alert("Save Success");
    }

    // onSaveError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onSaveError(contactError) {
        alert("Error = " + [contactError](../parameters/contactError.html).code);
    }

    // onRemoveSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onRemoveSuccess(contacts) {
        alert("Removal Success");
    }

    // onRemoveError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onRemoveError(contactError) {
        alert("Error = " + [contactError](../parameters/contactError.html).code);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Find Contacts</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to put all JavaScript Code in index.js file, not at index.html

Comment: @Sven you must build the app with cordova then install it on the device or else you cannot access contacts

Comment: Hello Akis. Sorry for my late answer. This was the correct hint. Thank you so much!!!!